# How to increment the the primary key of a table using a sequence?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Java code (JPA with Hibernate 4.1) to insert into an Oracle 12c database.

Table : Dept :

```
Name   Null     Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
DEPTNO NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
DNAME           VARCHAR2(14) 
LOC             VARCHAR2(13)
```

From Java code, I am inserting value for `DNAME` and `LOC` as 'Research','London'.

Entity class :

```
    @Entity(name="Department")
@Table(name="mydept")
public class Department {
    @Id 
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MYDEPT_SEQ", sequenceName ="MYDEPT_SEQ") 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYDEPT_SEQ")
    @Column(name="deptno")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="dname")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="loc")
    private String location;
```

Sequence :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SCOTT"."MYDEPT_SEQ"  MINVALUE 30 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 10 START WITH 80 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

But while inserting, `deptId` is being inserted with values -20, 0, 10.

Comment: Using <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/> in persistence.xml

Comment: drop the sequence and recreate it.